# Weak convergence of discrete distributions

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

I am trying to show that discrete distributions can converge weakly to a distribution that has a density.

My example would be to look at $$((0,1], \mathcal{B}_{(0,1]},P)$$ where $P$ is the Lebesgue measure. Then, I can define distribution functions $F_n(x)= .x_1x_2...x_n$, where the right hand side is the binary expansion of $x$.

I think this is discrete right ? Given that there are jumps only at points $k/2^n$

But I am not sure how to find the limiting distribution and prove my desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The r.v. coresponding to $F_n$ takes only rational values. Any r.v. that takes only countably many values is discrete.

$F_n(x) \to x$ and $F(x)=x, 0 \leq x \leq 1$ defines the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. Hence, your example works fine.

Note:

1. The Central Limit Theorem shows that there are plenty of examples of discrete distributions converging to  the standard normal distribution.
2. Binary expansion is not unique. So you will have to decide whether you want infinite expansions or finite expansions when there is non-uniqueness. This is only a minor point and it does not affect the final result. Also, it is not  obvious  that your $F_n$'s are right continuous. This  is also not serious. You could replace $F_n$ by $G_n$ where $G_n (x) =\lim_{y>x,y \to x} F_n(y)$.